# When I try to replace strings out of pandas series from a dictionary some half strings get converted into some value that resonates with half string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, replace

## My try is to replace keys in strings of pandas dataframe series in a loop from a dictionary.

## My code is botching up the replace in one instance where there are common characters of two replaced with values candidates.

```
mapped_lookup={'Ardy=': '0',
 'is=': '1',
'Hais':'22',
 'the=': '2',
 'best=': '3',
 'est=': '4',
 'est2=': '5'}

df['header'] = pd.Series(["[Ardy=4.2, is=402, the=100]", "[HAis=4.3, the=399, est=200]", "[HAis=4.4, is=398, C=150]"])


def replacer(value, mappings):
    for k, v in mappings.items():
        value = value.replace(k, v)
    return value


mapped_ok = {k.replace("=", ""): str(v) for k, v in mapped_lookup.items()}
df['Header']=df['Header'].apply(lambda x: replacer(x, mapped_ok))
```

## The output I want-

```
df['header'] = pd.Series(["[0=4.2, 1=402, 2=100]", "[22=4.3, 2=399, 4=200]", "[22=4.4, 1=398, C=150]"])
```

## The output I get with below code-

```
df['header'] = pd.Series(["[0=4.2, 1=402, 2=100]", "[HA1=4.3, 2=399, 4=200]", "[HA1=4.4, 1=398, C=150]"])
```

## How can I do this?

Comment: Because your replacer function loops through the dictionary sequentially. 'is' key is before 'HAis' and hence gets replaced first. To get to your desired output you could reorder the keys in your dictionary mapped_lookup.

Comment: After replacing the 'HAis' changes to 1 entirely instead of changing it halfway like it is in the post output and the way it is desired.

Comment: Don't quite understand your latest comment. Anyway, let me post the revised code as an answer and you can see if it works. For me, I get the desired output as per your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised code after reordering the dictionary keys in mapped_lookup.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mapped_lookup={'Ardy=': '0',
 'HAis':'22',
 'is=': '1',
 'the=': '2',
 'best=': '3',
 'est=': '4',
 'est2=': '5'}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Header'])

df['Header'] = pd.Series(["[Ardy=4.2, is=402, the=100]", "[HAis=4.3, the=399, est=200]", "[HAis=4.4, is=398, C=150]"])

def replacer(value, mappings):
    for k, v in mappings.items():
        value = value.replace(k, v)
    return value

mapped_ok = {k.replace("=", ""): str(v) for k, v in mapped_lookup.items()}
print(mapped_ok)

df['Header']=df['Header'].apply(lambda x: replacer(x, mapped_ok))

print(df['Header'])
```

With this code my output is:

```
0     [0=4.2, 1=402, 2=100]
1    [22=4.3, 2=399, 4=200]
2    [22=4.4, 1=398, C=150]
Name: Header, dtype: object
```